# Bootstrap3 radio buttons stacking is not happening properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, alignment, text-alignment

With Bootstrap3, stacking of radio buttons text is not happening properly in mobile(xs) view- [bootply](http://bootply.com/101489).

Screen shot:

[image]

As can be seen, text is not properly aligned to radio buttons in mobile(xs) view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the `.jumbotron` line-height..

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
    line-height:20px;
}
```

http://bootply.com/101503